# Application settings in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, application-settings, settings.bundle

I am trying to put the settings of an APP within the app it self, right now the settings are within the IOS Application SettingsBundle. I named the Settings Bundle folder to InAppSettings.bundle, they disappear from IOS Application Setting but not appearing within the app...

Are there some more changes within the code/project which I have to make???

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to add some code to parse the settings bundle and create a UI to display and edit it. You might want to look at [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit) which does much of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: look at its Settings.bundle and the plist inside, it's really easy to understand